# How to have a priority queue in Rails that sends jobs to several NodeJS servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, priority-queue, resque, sidekiq

I have a Rails app and a set of NodeJS servers. I use those NodeJS servers to parse URLs using PhantomJS. From my Rails app I know which NodeJS servers are ready to receive a URL to be parsed, and once it is parsed, the result is sent asynchronously back to the Rails server.

My problem is that if I will need a queue in Rails so that the URLs that need to be parsed are queued until some of the NodeJS servers are ready to parse. So, my question is:

What would be a good **priority-queue solution in Rails/Ruby** that would let me keep checking the queue and the status of the NodeJS servers and send the job from that queue to the free NodeJS server.

*I have used Sidekiq before, but I believe that in this case this is not necessary as the Worker would not do any expensive job here, but just delegating from the Rails queue to one of the NodeJS servers.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Redis with [BLPOP](http://redis.io/commands/BLPOP), for example. Just create a list for each level of priority. Have rails push URLs into the respective list for its priority, and the blocking pop waits for jobs to show up. Simple and lightweight, and redis should be well supported by both platforms in use.

But really, you could adapt almost any centralized storage into a home-rolled priority queue mechanism - for example you could get away with polling a table in a run of the mill RDBMS, as long as it has a priority and status (ready, running, complete, error, etc.) column that you can filter and sort. Not that I'd recommend that solution for a high volume use case, but it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My next question would be, once the priority queue is set, how do you poll the jobs from it? Do you have some kind of cron that keeps checking if there is something in the queue, or how do you do it?

Comment: The beauty of a blocking operation is that you don't need to poll. When your client issues the BLPOP command, it will sit idle (better known as blocking, hence the name) until a message shows up.

I found the following example code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pEUW0G56

I cannot guarantee that it is correct since I have not tried it myself, but from looking at it, I can see that at least the concept is on the right track.

Comment: but when the message shows up, who manages it? I need a class or something to be able to manage when that happens right?